# css selector on IE

Tags: css

I'm using .class1.class2 .class3 selector, where .class1.class is a combination selector and .class3 belongs to a descendant.  works fine in FF, but on IE7, it doesn't work.
In the css below,  the second style is always shown in IE.  any solution?

```
 
<STYLE type="text/css">
.test1.test2 .test3{
    width:90px;
    height:100px;
}
.test4.test2 .test3{
    width:900px;
    height:100px;
}
</style>


<div class="test1 test2">
    <button value="test" class="test3"/>
</div>
```

Comment: You can do a `.test1 .test3` selector, or a `.test2 .test3`, unless you need to exclude the combination, can you re-order to where either parent works, or does it have to be the combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That style should work perfectly on IE7+. As Pekka said in the comments there is a [small problem with IE6](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multipleclasses.html). I'm guessing that you're not using the strict doctype perhaps?
<sub>In which case, you deserve everything you get :-o</sub>

Just add `<!doctype html>` to the start of the HTML file and everything should be fine.

Comment: seems like everyone except Nick misunderstood the question, the css in question is
.test1.test2<SPACE>.test3

Comment: adding <!doctype html> works.  But I'm already using IE7, not IE6

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear - the strict doctype is to make it work in IE7. Not sure what you mean in your first comment; I know what the CSS is. IE's problem is using two classes on one element i.e. the `.test1.test2` part

Answer (score 4):

just for let you know, what you are using is called **Multiple Classes** method! **IE7** need to use this form:

```
div.class1.class2 div.class3 {}
```

**IE6** don't suppurt this you can hack it, read the solution

> http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multipleclasses.html

hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Conditional Comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) , this issue has been raised too many times here is an example :

```
<!--[if lte IE 9>
<style type="text/css">
.test1,.test2,.test3{
    width:90px;
    height:100px;
}
.test4,.test2,.test3{
    width:900px;
    height:100px;
}
</style>

<![endif]-->
```

This means all IE family browser less than version 9 are going to read in this style, or you can use style with # to be read by IE like this :

```
<STYLE type="text/css">
.test1,.test2,.test3{
    #width:90px;
    #height:100px;
}
.test4,.test2,.test3{
    #width:900px;
    #height:100px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: But why? I still don't understand why IE would get this wrong in the first place.

Comment: But the example you provided is not a combination, I have .test1.test2 as a combination and .test3 belongs to a descendant.